# Anti-idle software against screensaver

Tags: windows, software-rec

I need a software like **Caffeine** to simulate keypress periodically. Unfortunately with **Caffeine** I can't configure which key to press and not happy with its default.

Comment: Moving the mouse a bit is probably safer than pressing keys. I recall some programs that would “jitter” the mouse a bit to prevent the screensaver, and they were generally pretty configurable, but I can’t find them at the moment. I’ll check my system to see if I can find one.

Comment: Would the alternative (more straight-forward) approach of "a software that can temporarily disable the screensaver" also work for you?

Comment: Yes, that could (probably) also work, in which case, something like [BlockAPM](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Block-APM-and-Screen-Saver.shtml) would be an option.

Comment: Sorry guys, disabling screensaver is not an option due to some circumstancies.

Comment: @Synetech inc.: pressing scroll lock is much safer. Moving mouse is not so good if you are working along with that anti-idle software and actively using mouse. Then every time I have to enable/disable software not to disrupt myself.

Comment: Did you try BlockAPM? It just sits in the notification area (“tray”) and blocks the screensaver (and power-savings) from activating; it does not actually *disable* anything (ie, it does not *change* any settings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one reviews very well (4/5), and was lean when I installed it (only 36K) on a test comp. You don't say what OS, but it is also tested through Vista, so probably also runs on Windows 7. It is freeware.

http://eng.softq.org/small_utils.htm (Anti ScreenSaver).

Comment: Looks like it works!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.